# When merging 2 variables, concat does not print them the way i want it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

Currently the program is as follows:

a1

```
      Salary
Year        
2007    2750
2008    2850
2009    2700
2010    2900
2011    3000
2012    3050
2013    3050
2014    3200
2015    3300
2016    3300
```

b1

```
      GDP for Year
Year              
2007      271249.8
2008      271980.4
2009      279858.0
2010      322361.1
2011      346649.0
2012      361365.9
2013      378531.6
2014      390447.7
2015      408096.6
2016      410271.9
```

When I merge it, it shows:

```
pd.concat([a1, b1], axis=1, ignore_index=False)

      Salary  GDP for Year
Year                      
2007  2750.0           NaN
2008  2850.0           NaN
2009  2700.0           NaN
2010  2900.0           NaN
2011  3000.0           NaN
2012  3050.0           NaN
2013  3050.0           NaN
2014  3200.0           NaN
2015  3300.0           NaN
2016  3300.0           NaN
2007     NaN      271249.8
2008     NaN      271980.4
2009     NaN      279858.0
2010     NaN      322361.1
2011     NaN      346649.0
2012     NaN      361365.9
2013     NaN      378531.6
```

I would like for it to be printed as:

```
        Salary   GDP For Year
Year    
2007    2750 .   271249.8
2008    2850 .   271980.4
2009    2700 .  279858.0
2010    2900 .  322361.1
2011    3000 .   346649.0
2012    3050 .   361365.9
2013    3050 .   378531.6
2014    3200 .   390447.7
2015    3300 .   408096.6
2016    3300 .   410271.9
```

and then after that, i would like to plot a graph and create a comparison as to how the 2 lines compare to each other in a single graph.

I've tried, merge, join, concat but nothing so far.

Answer (score 1):

One of the dataframe's indices is of type string while the other is integer

#### `rename`

```
a1.rename(int, inplace=True)
b1.rename(int, inplace=True)
pd.concat([a1, b1], axis=1)

      Salary  GDP for Year
Year                      
2007    2750      271249.8
2008    2850      271980.4
2009    2700      279858.0
2010    2900      322361.1
2011    3000      346649.0
2012    3050      361365.9
2013    3050      378531.6
2014    3200      390447.7
2015    3300      408096.6
2016    3300      410271.9
```

---

#### assign to `index`

```
a1.index = a1.index.astype(int)
b1.index = b1.index.astype(int)
pd.concat([a1, b1], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pd.concat([a1, b1], axis='col', ignore_index=False)
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the suggestion will keep in mind when answering next time.